# How to read .pgm file and allocate memory using malloc?

Tags: c, image, malloc, pgm

I am new to compiling in linux environment. Anyway, I have a source code in C which is suppose to read a sequence of .pgm image files, compress them and write the compressed file to a new .pgm file. However, when I compile I get the following error message

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fefc6176010 ***  
======= Backtrace: =========  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a6e6)[0x7fefda73b6e6]  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7fefda73f9cc]  
./a.out[0x408491]  
./a.out[0x408565]  
./a.out[0x401048]  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fefda6e230d]  
./a.out[0x400a59]  
======= Memory map: ========    
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 299109                             /home/skyjuice/PROJECT3/a.out  
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 07:00 299109                             /home/skyjuice/PROJECT3/a.out  
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 07:00 299109                             /home/skyjuice/PROJECT3/a.out  
0060c000-059f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
05ebb000-05ee3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]  
7fefc0000000-7fefc0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefc0021000-7fefc4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefc59d3000-7fefc59d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefc5f60000-7fefc5f75000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 2117                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fefc5f75000-7fefc6174000 ---p 00015000 07:00 2117                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fefc6174000-7fefc6175000 r--p 00014000 07:00 2117                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fefc6175000-7fefc6176000 rw-p 00015000 07:00 2117                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  
7fefc6176000-7fefda6c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefda6c1000-7fefda858000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 904195                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so  
7fefda858000-7fefdaa57000 ---p 00197000 07:00 904195                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so  
7fefdaa57000-7fefdaa5b000 r--p 00196000 07:00 904195                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so  
7fefdaa5b000-7fefdaa5c000 rw-p 0019a000 07:00 904195                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so  
7fefdaa5c000-7fefdaa62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefdaa62000-7fefdaae5000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 904199                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so  
7fefdaae5000-7fefdace4000 ---p 00083000 07:00 904199                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so  
7fefdace4000-7fefdace5000 r--p 00082000 07:00 904199                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so  
7fefdace5000-7fefdace6000 rw-p 00083000 07:00 904199                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so  
7fefdace6000-7fefdad07000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 644102                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so  
7fefdaeeb000-7fefdaeee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefdaf04000-7fefdaf06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   
7fefdaf06000-7fefdaf07000 r--p 00020000 07:00 644102                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so  
7fefdaf07000-7fefdaf09000 rw-p 00021000 07:00 644102                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so  
7fff1b020000-7fff1b0ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]  
7fff1b148000-7fff1b149000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]  
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]  
Aborted
```

Below is a snippet of the source code

#define START_FRAME 141
    #define END_FRAME 143
    #define SKIP_FRAME 1
    #define INPUT_STRING "/home/image%03d.pgm"

```
int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{

  unsigned char *frm1, *frm2, *predict, *predictDb, *frm1E;    
  unsigned char *rcnDiff, *diff, *rcnFrm1, *rcnFrm2, *wave;  
  int           *xVct, *yVct, *pxE, *pyE, *code;  
  int   nx  = 1920, ny = 1080, nxy;  
  int   bSize  = 16, nbx, nby, nbxy;
  int   frameNo = START_FRAME;  
  int   nxy  = nx * ny;

  frm1       = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  frm2       = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  rcnFrm1    = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  rcnFrm2    = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  predict    = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  predictDb  = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  diff       = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  rcnDiff    = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);  
  wave       = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);    
  xVct       = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * nbxy);  
  yVct       = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * nbxy);  

  code       = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * tgtBits1);    
  frm1d      = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  frm2d      = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  predictd   = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  predictDbd = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  rcnFrm1d   = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  rcnFrm2d   = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  wavFrm1    = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  wavDiff    = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  wavRcnFrm1 = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  wavRcnDiff = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  diffd      = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  
  rcnDiffd   = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxy);  

  frm1Ed     = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * nxE * nyE);  
  frm1E      = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxE * nyE);

  //read file from PGM and store into frm1  
  frameNo = START_FRAME;  
  sprintf(fileName, INPUT_STRING, frameNo);  
  readPgm(frm1, fileName, nx, ny);  

  //after some operations

  //write into a new PGM file  
   sprintf(fileName, "predictDb%03d.pgm", frameNo);  
   writePgm(predictDb, fileName, nx, ny);  

  return 0; //end of main function   
}  

//read original frame  
void readPgm(unsigned char *frame, char * fileName, int nx, int ny) {  
  int i, j;  
  FILE *file;  
  char str[128];  

  file = fopen(fileName,"r");  
  if (file == 0) {  
    printf("Open error in File read \n");  
      }  
  fgets(str, 100, file);  
  for(j = 0; j < ny; j++) {  
      for(i = 0; i < nx; i++) {  
    fscanf(file,"%d", (int *)&frame[i + nx * j]);  
      }  
  }  
  fclose(file);  
}  


//create frame  
void writePgm(unsigned char *frame, char *fileName, int nx, int ny){  
  int i, j;  
  FILE *file;  

  file = fopen(fileName, "w");  
  fprintf(file, "P2 %d %d 255\n", nx, ny);  
  for(j = 0; j < ny; j++) {  
    for(i = 0; i < nx; i++) {  
      fprintf(file,"%d ", frame[i + nx * j]);  
    }  
    fprintf(file, "\n");  
  }  
  fclose(file);  
}
```

Can anyone help identify what the problem is? Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like you initialize `nxy` before you use it. After that none of your `malloc`s will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `nxy` and most other variables you use in the calls to `malloc()`. Those variables then can contain random values and you will not allocate the correct amounts of memory.

Comment: Sorry, I actually did initialize nyz but did not include it in my code above. So I guess the problem is not due to this. Anymore possible causes?

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
int   /* ... */, nxy;   
frm1  = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nxy);
```

means that you allocate memory based on uninitialized value (`nxy`), which can be anything (whatever garbage is in memory where `nxy` is allocated.

Then you pass this unknown length buffer to

```
readPgm(frm1, fileName, nx, ny);
```

and attempt to access `frame[i + nx * j]`

If `nxy` is less than `nx*ny`, you are corrupting memory by writing past the allocated space.

To fix, make sure you initialize all variables properly.  E.g.:

```
int nxy = nx*ny;
```

Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) on why you should not cast the return value of `malloc` -- `void *` (the return type of `malloc`) will be implicitly converted to the correct type

Comment: Sorry, I actually did initialize nyz but did not include it in my code above. So I guess the problem is not due to this. Anymore possible causes?

Comment: The other problem is that you allocate nxy _characters_ worth of data for the frame, but when access it, you cast the pointer to pointer-to-_int_.  You either need to read a simple unsigned char in `fscanf`, or change `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(int)` when allocating the frame (and change its type to `int*` as well).  In either case you will not need the cast in the `fscanf`

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be Linux specific - the C code should work in any environment, even Windows.

Compile with `gcc -g` (or even `gcc -ggdb`) to get line numbers in that error backtrace (and to enable easier debugging with gdb).

I don't see where you call free() to release memory that you allocated using malloc(). If you don't, the memory is released when the process exits. I suspect you have an off-by-one that overflows into memory that contains a pointer, and overwrites the address in the pointer with garbage. Then when you try to release a chunk of memory that begins at this "address" the operation fails. Compile with debug information, run your program in gdb (`gdb --args ./myprogram arg1 arg2`, `start`, `next`, `step`, `continue`) and see where the problem occurs. To help debug memory issues (like writes outside a buffer) use valgrind.